# How to route traffic between overlapping subnets on GCP from different projects/VPCs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, routes, google-compute-engine, vpc

In GPC we need to allow VMs on VPC A Subnet 1 to communicate with VMs on other VPCs (in other projects) where there subnets overlap (exchange originates from A).
eg.
Project A | VPC A | Subnet 1 | 10.10.142.0/24
Project B | VPC B | Subnet 1 | 10.10.12.0/24
Project C | VPC C | Subnet 1 | 10.10.12.0/24

We have ruled out VPC Sharing due to a lack of project administration autonomy. And also ruled out VPC Peering due to not coping with overlapping subsets.

And have tried:
NCC with spokes and a Private NAT, and with just Project A and Project B we were able to get a VM on each to SSH (with appropriate FW rules). But when adding C, we need to filter the CIDR 10.10.12.0/24 for both B and C spokes. And after re-adding the spokes, of course now there are no routes from A to B anymore and of course none for A to C (ie. subnets have to be filtered to allow overlap).

I think I need to add routes, but the gcloud command seems to need --net-external-ip-pool, which I do not have/want, as this all needs to be internal and not public.

How best to proceed to be able to route A to B and A to C. VPN maybe... VPC Peering with PNAT (although I think the same problem as the NCC solution we tried described above).

[Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vlo0D.png)

Comment: You cannot have overlapping networks. Delete one and recreate it. That is your only solution.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley.

But surely that is not true. Even Google provide instructions on connecting VPC with overlapping Subnets using NCC and a Private NAT - see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x6P3NwiPmP4.

Where the solution masks spokes with overlapping subnets and reaches in via a Private NAT. But I guess the NAT is in the wrong direction and with this NAT reversed and forwarding, this can be achieved?

And of course there is VPC Sharing which does take case of overlapping subnets (but I prefer not to use this)..

Comment: Be careful with using gimmicks and tricks when networking in the cloud. For example, you can put a NAT in front of a VPC and assign the NAT a public IP address. Now traffic is public and you will be charged for egress traffic for both networks, which can be very expensive. The better you understand networking, the more you will understand my first comment.

Comment: Yeah, that is a good point, @JohnHanley. I have noticed that the standard NAT and VPN both require public IP addresses - thanks for the note.

Regarding the NAT, I was using the Private NAT as this does not require a Public IP, but because the NAT is SNAT'ing, it did not work in my case anyhow.

Was also looking at using a Router Appliance so I can DNAT... not sure about this...

I guess it is either VPC Sharing, or as you say, recreate subnets :(

Comment: Read this [document](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/manage-destination-overlap) which shows a few techniques for overlapping networks. All require special configuration and management and some require advanced skills. Some create black holes that will cause headaches later. The next network admin will then wonder why the networks were not configured correctly to start with.